# Update nested Attributes on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 4 usually updating a nested attributes we do:

and in rails 3? should user params.require?

```
def sent

@user.update_attributes(order_params)

  def order_params
  params.require(:user).permit( order_attributes: [:track_number])
end 

end




class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gem `strong parameter` in rails 3

Link: [strong parameter gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

and If you do not want to add separate gem for this you can allow the parameter by `attr_accessible`. (*This is default and ideal way of allowing parameters*).

Ref: [attr_accessible document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)

Edit: 
  To allow nested attributes in `attr_accessible` you have to use this [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Comment: @japalow: Edited the answer. Please refer that link.